# Can this Python loop be expressed more succinctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, refactoring

I've come across some Python v2.7 code that I have refactored to become this:

```
for ssid in (ssid for ssid in overlaps
             if ssid != subseq_id and ssid not in merged):
```

But it feels to me that there should be a way to express this without using two `for` statements?

Comment: Strictly that's one `for` statement containing one list comprehension, not two `for` statements. It's a sort of coincidence that the keyword `for` has both uses.

Comment: @minopret it's not a list comprehension, it's a generator expression

Comment: ok, yes, it produces a lazy list rather than a strict list so since I said "strictly" I might have delved into that detail too :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `filter()`:

```
for ssid in filter(lambda s: s != subseq_id and s not in merged, overlaps):
    # ...
```

or you could just test *in the loop*:

```
for ssid in overlaps:
    if ssid == subseq_id or ssid in merged:
      continue
    # ...
```

Comment: +1 for the second option. May be more efficient to swap the tests if you don't expect `ssid == subseq_id` to be `True` very often

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data (order is not important, ...), you could use sets :

```
excluded = set(merged)
excluded.add(subseq_id)
ssids = set(overlaps) - excluded
for ssid in ssids:
    ...
```